# Debugging a Postfix Saslauthd PAM-PGsql authentication failure

Tags: postfix, postgresql, pam, saslauthd

I've set up pam-pgsql to lookup passwords in my database for Postfix via Saslauthd.

I can test credentials using the command line:

```
$ sudo testsaslauthd -u user@email.com -p password

0: NO "authentication failed"
```

Authentication will fail, and I don't know why.

```
$ sudo tail /var/log/auth.log

Feb  5 15:33:12 saslauthd[7460]: pam_unix(imap:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb  5 15:33:12 saslauthd[7460]: pam_unix(imap:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=
Feb  5 15:33:14 saslauthd[7460]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
Feb  5 15:33:14 saslauthd[7460]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=user@email.com] [service=imap] [realm=] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
```

How can I know what pam-pgsql is doing? How can I get more helpful messages?

Answer (score 2):

Jon from the past! I have the answer to all your problems.

There's a clue right in your log:

```
saslauthd[8044]: pam_unix(imap:auth): check pass; user unknown
```

Remember how you put the PAM config in `/etc/pam.d/smtp` and not `imap`? And your log says `imap`? Yup, you're trying to auth on the wrong service.

I actually found the solution in the Postfix SASL manual, just under [where you found that Sasl test command](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#testing_saslauthd):

> #### Testing saslauthd authentication
>
> Specify an additional "`-s smtp`" if saslauthd was configured to contact the PAM authentication framework

Yup, you will soon find that the right invocation is rather:

```
$ sudo testsaslauthd -u user@email.com -p password -s smtp
0: OK "Success."
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have config this module through it's config file /etc/pam_pgsql.conf which accepts debug parameter:

```
    database = db
    user = user
    [...]
    debug = 1
```

There's also a global debug parameter you should append to pam config lines:

```
    auth        required    pam_pgsql.so debug
```

source: [[github] Official repo](https://github.com/pam-pgsql/pam-pgsql)

Comment: Good idea, but didn't apply in my case. Still, a good answer to the question.